# Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: StageWebView

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am using flash builder 4.0 and am getting the following error.  I have tied both 3.5 SDK and 4.0 SDK and set the flash version to 10 or above.  I also tried a friends computer with flash builder 4.5 but could not resolve the error either.

Based on the Adobe link below StageWebView is part of AS3 which as I understand should be included with my current project as part of the flash.media.* group but I don't see it when I type the import statement.

Can someone tell me how to add StageWebView to a project or what I am doing wrong?

Error message:
Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: StageWebView

Related link:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html

Comment: StageWebView is for Adobe AIR only, not for Flash Web applications.

Comment: Ok, well between the suggested edit and you comment I guess I have may answer.  I am trying to put it in a flash application and it only runs on AIR.  Would mark it as answered but I don't see how to do that with only a comment to go by.  But thanks!

Comment: Don't worry about marking it as correct or anything. A Single-line answer isn't really worthy, i feel. But good to know that I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

StageWebView and many other classes are just for use with Adobe AIR, although they are included in the flash packages. sometimes also object methods are only available to AIR.

[image]

you recognize what is available only to AIR by the little red triangle logo in the [reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html).

Adobe AIR is not available in the web plugin. It is used to create "standalone" applications for desktop and mobile.

Comment: Thanks, very enlightening.  I did not realize the bit about the icon meaning it was only supported by air.